# Automatically refreshing the page when a start button is pressed until a stop button is pressed. how to keep the start button press time

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am continuously updating a table of data from latest value in the database. To do so, page is refreshing automatically (every 10 seconds). The process will start when the user press start button and will end when the user press end button. I need the start button press time. the problem is, as the page is refreshing, the start time is updating to page refresh time. I just need the start button press time (time the user pressed start). any help?

```
  if (!isset($_GET['stop'])){

    if (isset($_GET['start'])){
        date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Bangkok");

        $date_clicked = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        echo "Time the button was clicked: " . $date_clicked . "<br>";
//to refresh page every 10 seconds
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10"/>';


        echo "Data is updating...";
        echo "<br>";

  //code to display data in a table from DB
}

}
```

Comment: Why not use Ajax to update the part of the page that needs updating? Then the page won't need to reload and your JS will keep any values you set.

Answer (score 0):

The way to use `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10"/>` is into the `head` tag.

See the example below:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Your title</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10" />
</head>

<body>
  Time the button was clicked:
  <?= $date_clicked ?> <br />
</body>

</html>
```